# Node process object made available to browser client code

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to understand how webpack uses DefinePlugin. I have:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
}),
```

and a function:

```
export const foo = () => {
  console.log(process)
  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
}
window.foo = foo
```

when I print foo, I see the following in my browser console:

```
ƒ foo() {
  console.log(process);
  console.log("development");
}
```

It seems like the variable "development" was injected while webpack was compiling the input file. At the same time webpack also injected the process object into the JavaScript code, and the browser did print out the process object when foo was called:

```
{title: "browser", browser: true, env: {…}, argv: Array(0), nextTick: ƒ, …}
```

My question is, how can the process object, which is a Node concept, be made available to the browser?

In fact, if I do:

```
window.process = process
```

I can use process.nextTick right inside the browser console! I thought the nextTick function was a Node-specific implementation! Could anybody explain this?

Thank you!

Comment: Because webpack is a nodejs app

Comment: When you switch off DefinePlugin, do you still have process object on the front-end?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node-process, the webpack can make polyfills for different node functions, but it appears as the `node.process` is a `"mock"`;

> "mock": Provide a mock that implements the expected interface but has little or no functionality.

Have you tested it to see if it actually works? It might just be an empty shell.

If it works I assume that the plugin actually uses something like [node-process](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-process/blob/master/browser.js) as shown in this blog-post: http://timnew.me/blog/2014/06/23/process-nexttick-implementation-in-browser/

Copied from that blogpost:

```
process.nextTick = (function () {
    var canSetImmediate = typeof window !== 'undefined'
    && window.setImmediate;
    var canPost = typeof window !== 'undefined'
    && window.postMessage && window.addEventListener;
    if (canSetImmediate) {
        return function (f) { return window.setImmediate(f) };
    }
    if (canPost) {
        var queue = [];
        window.addEventListener('message', function (ev) {
            var source = ev.source;
            if ((source === window || source === null) && ev.data === 'process-tick') {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                if (queue.length > 0) {
                    var fn = queue.shift();
                    fn();
                }
            }
        }, true);
        return function nextTick(fn) {
            queue.push(fn);
            window.postMessage('process-tick', '*');
        };
    }
    return function nextTick(fn) {
        setTimeout(fn, 0);
    };
})();
```

It is a bit hard to know for sure from the info you provided. If it truly works I think it is very likely you have [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) enabled in your node app. Perhaps you find some of what you need here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/transform-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

Hopefully you find this answer somewhat helpful.

**The bottom line is that I believe it is a polyfill from somewhere.**

Comment: The only polyfill I use is:

`import 'babel-polyfill'`

Does that define process.nextTick?

Comment: It might. But as I mention in my answer, webpack itself has polyfills, but some of it is only an "mock". You might be able to run a `.toString()` on the method and see the code. If its empty it is probably from webpack itself, if it has code you can try to google that code and hopefully find out where it comes from.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a polyfill, not a mock. It won't have 100% functionality, but for any methods that makes sense in the browser it will try to do something equivalent for you. They have this built into webpack because so many node modules depend on process. I don't think it is included by default in a build though. I'm guessing you have a dependency that requires it.

Answer (score 6):

How webpack deals with [Node globals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/) and [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) are actually two different concerns.

Default **node globals** are **globally injected**, while **constants** defined in `webpack.DefinePlugin` are physically **replaced one by one** trough all the codebase.

eg:

```
// config
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
  'process.env.MY_VAR': {foo: JSON.stringify('bar')},
}),

// source
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV', process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log('process.env.MY_VAR', process.env.MY_VAR);

console.log('process.env', process.env);
console.log('process', process);

// compiled
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV', "development");
console.log('process.env.MY_VAR', __webpack_require__.i({"foo":"bar"}));
console.log('process.env', process.env);
console.log('process', process);
```

Note that `process.env.NODE_ENV` and `process.env.MY_VAR` p**hysically are replaced**, while `process.env` and `process` **keep their reference** to the injected `process` **mock**.

But `webpack.DefinePlugin` is also able to **override the mocked `process` object** (or just part of it): a lot of power which implies the risk of getting **unexpected behaviours**.

From [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#feature-flags):

> When defining values for process prefer 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') over process: { env: { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') } }. Using the latter will overwrite the process object which can break compatibility with some modules that expect other values on the process object to be defined.

eg:

```
// config
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process': JSON.stringify('override'),
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
}),

// source
console.log('process', process);
console.log('process.env', process.env);
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV', process.env.NODE_ENV);


// compiled
console.log('process', "override");
console.log('process.env', "override".env);          // [boum!]
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV', "development");  // [replaced by DefinePlugin!]
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer this question, but it was the solution I needed.  I was trying to access `process` in code that webpack compiled, intending the compiled code to be run in a NodeJS environment rather than in the browser.  The `process` variable doesn't exist on `window`, but on `global`.

The solution was to set the `target` in the webpack config.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const config = {
    // ...
    target: 'node',
    // ...
};

module.exports = config;
```

This removes the `window` mock.

Answer (score 0):

see
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node

These options configure whether to polyfill or mock certain Node.js globals and modules. This allows code originally written for the Node.js environment to run in other environments like the browser.

This feature is provided by webpack's internal NodeStuffPlugin plugin. If the target is "web" (default) or "webworker", the NodeSourcePlugin plugin is also activated.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to assume you are experimenting with this on your local webpack dev server and not in your production build. Webpack dev server utilizes websockets for real time communication between the underlying node processes and the front-end bundle. If you wanted to utilize this in a production environment you would need to set up a socket between your front end JS and your node instance to send commands. From a security perspective it sounds like a nightmare, but may have some valid use cases.